# How to store the result of different jobs in GITLAB CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have three jobs defined in my pipeline. Three jobs run on three different runners. I need the job URL for each job at the end. So I will be using ${CI_JOB_URL} environment variable in each job. But what I need is I should be able to remember all these 3 values after all the job gets over.

I can't use **Variables** of YAML. Because those are immutable. I also can't define environment variables inside my job because they will be cleared once the job is done. What I need is some kind of collection that adds the URL of each job once the job is over.

Is this possible?

I have read about caching, artifacts and distributed caching as well. Before trying out all of these, I just wanted to know if there was any other workaround for this. Because exploiting the cache/artifacts just for remembering 3 strings makes the process a little bit complicated.

```
job1:
    tags:
         windows
    script:
          #do something.
          #Get job URL
job2
    tags:
         linux
    script:
          #do something.
          #Get job URL
job3
    tags:
         macOS
    script:
          #do something.
          #Get job URL
job4
    script:
          #Finally get all my JOB urls in a collection or some variables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitLab jobs API to get a list of jobs for a pipeline.

GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs

You can use the scope parameter to get jobs of specific status: created, pending, running, failed, success, canceled, skipped, or manual. All jobs are returned if scope is not provided.

Example:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_ID/jobs?scope[]=success'
```